# Samsung 10 plus won't allow wifi p2p discovery

Tags: java, android, p2p, wifip2p, samsung-galaxy

I wrote an Android app to allow a device to discover nearby devices via Wi-Fi P2P discovery. I am following [this doc](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).

The app works beautifully on my Samsung Tab E tablet -- I am able to scan and find other devices when the app is running on the tablet. But I am unable to even activate the peer discovery process when running the app on my Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus.  My Samsung s10 Plus won't even appear on my tablet's list of available peers unless I manually go into my Galaxy S10 Plus's settings and enable `Wi-Fi Discovery Mode`. At that point, my Tab E tablet can "see" my Galaxy S10 Plus, but as soon as I exit the settings screen on the Galaxy s10 Plus, Wi-Fi discovery is turned back off and I am no longer able to see it as a potential p2p peer.

Is there a way to allow peer discovery on a Samsung s10 Plus? I am unable to test out my app without it and would rather not have to purchase another Tab E to test p2p connectivity.

Below is the code my app is running for reference:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    ListView listView;
    TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    EditText writeMsg;

    //For programmatically turning wifi on and off:
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    //For keeping track of available clients to connect to
    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] deviceNameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialWork();
        //initializeButtonOnClickListeners();

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        btnDiscover = (Button)findViewById(R.id.discover);
        connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);

//        btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
//        read_msg_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
//        writeMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        initializeOnClickListeners();
    }


    private void initializeOnClickListeners() {

        //Set up functionality for when the discover button is clicked.
        btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "looking for a new peer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Failed to start");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //Define the logic for when a new peer is discovered
    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)) {
                //clear the peers
                peers.clear();

                //store device list
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index = 0;

                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()) {
                    deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                    deviceArray[index] = device;
                    index++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        deviceNameArray);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            if(peers.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Devices Found :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener myPeerListListener;

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, MainActivity mActivity) {
        this.mManager = mManager;
        this.mChannel = mChannel;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println("The following action was received: " + action);

        if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);

            //if wifi is enabled
            if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "INSIDE THE P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, mActivity.peerListListener);
                Toast.makeText(context, "A new peer has been found!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do something
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in Android for sometimes, but I think my experience might still valid, you can give it a try.

Correct me if I'm wrong, so, you have developed an app that allows your devices to discover and connect to each other, without the need to access to the phone's settings. For your S10, you have installed and opened the app, but you cannot discover it via your Tab, unless you manually switch it on in the settings?

First, ensure your app has all the required permission added and requested when using the app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.nsdchat"
    ...
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Just to make sure your app has the permission, add the permission to the code below for the respective permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
}
...
```

Second, look at the code library version. Since s10 + is fairly new, Android has actually enhanced the privacy and security starting from Android 8.0. The code you wrote might be outdated due to the library version, and some APIs might be deprecated.